# Filtering Excel Table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I am trying to filter an Excel table automatically, through VBA.

The table has a number of rows and is currently in B5:N584 of Sheet2.
The first column of the table has "Country" as header and that's the column I want to apply the filter to. I would like the table to filter automatically depending on the country name, inputted by the user. The country name will be on cell B3 of Sheet2, now defined as "=Sheet1!A1" which is where the user inputs the country.

The way I would like it to work is:
- The user writes a country name on cell A1 of Sheet1.
- The country is automatically pulled to cell B3 of Sheet2.
- The Table is filtered, in the first column, according to the content of cell B3 of Sheet2.

This is the VBA code I have written:

```
    Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Target.Address = Range("B3").Address Then
       Range("B5:N584").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("B2:B3")
   End If

End Sub
```

On cell B2 I have written "Country" just like in the column header.

What I have done is almost working. The only problem is that the filter is not being applied automatically. The user-inputted country on cell A1 is pulled to cell B3 of Sheet2 but the filter is not applied until I click on the formula bar of cell B3 and click enter without changing anything - then the filter is applied to the table below.

I am wondering what might be preventing the table from automatically detecting there is a new country on cell B2 without be having to click on the cell and pressing ENTER.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set your worksheet to trigger the code when the user has entered the data in Cell A1 so you detect a change in this cell and trigger the code rather than wait B3 to be changed.

```
   If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
   Range("B5:N584").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("B2:B3")
```

End If

Comment: Thank you for your help. How would I do that if A1 is in another sheet? How do I refer the other sheet in the "=Range()"?

Comment: You'd have to put the `WOrksheet_Change` event handler in the *other* sheet, and then qualify the `Range` to which sheet it needs to be operating against (e.g., `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B5:...`)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have two sheets called Sheet1 and Sheet2 and the table is on Sheet2 in the range you specified.

Also assuming the following cases...

1. User inputs the Country name in A1 on Sheet1.
2. On Sheet2 B2 has the header Country same as the header in B5 in the table.
3. B3 on Sheet2 has a formula =Sheet1!A1

Make sure all the above assumptions are correct, remove the change event code from Sheet1 Module and then place the following code on Sheet2 Module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B5").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B3")
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

Actually you can remove the sheet reference because the code is on the Sheet2 Module itself.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Range("B5").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("B2:B3")
End Sub
```